# How to display single field in div for drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

How to display custom_field in a separate div

I'm using Drupal 7.27

Refer to Screen shot with machine name: **field_bottom_content**

I tried the following code:

```
print render($content['field_bottom_content']);
```

but, its not working.....

[image]

Comment: <?php print render($content['field_bottom_content']); ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
print $node->field_bottom_content['und'][0]['value'];
```

Try this one.

Comment: Explanation might help since you are using pointers and a 3-index array.

Comment: $node is the built in variable of the drupal. "field_bottom_content" is the name of the custom field. "und" is used for the language "0" is the index and "value" will return the actual value of the field. Hope this explanation helps!

Comment: I have written this code in one of my node template file. I hope you are doing this in the same place.

Comment: I need to display taxonomy pages

Comment: Can you please explain your actual need? As in the question you have mentioned that you need to display the custom field and now you want to display taxonomy pages. Please stick to any one solution at one time. For another issue raised another question.